# defined code executes before called upon using tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, definition

I am working on a program that lets users store their usernames and passwords, and hashes the plaintext where they are stored (hence the commented out hashing code). However, I am using tkinter for the GUI, and one of my buttons runs a defined function before it's called. (ignore all seemingly random comments please)

```
import basehash
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import os
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
from string import ascii_lowercase

userPaths = ['./usernames2.txt', './username.txt', './usernames3.txt']
passPaths = ['./Passwords2.txt', './Passwords.txt', './Passwords3.txt']
#create new doc and assign doc array
# use an array for password of paths where the password is stored on a plaintext file
password = ("test") 
usernameguess1 = ("")
passwordguess1 = ("")
loggedin = 0
activeUser = ""
activeUserNum = 0
hashbase = basehash.base52()

LETTERS = {letter: str(index) for index, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, start=1)} 

def alphabet_position(text):
    text = text.lower()

    numbers = [LETTERS[character] for character in text if character in LETTERS]

    return ''.join(numbers)

def loginpage():

    #Gui Formatting
    root = tkinter.Toplevel()
    root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    root.title("HasherTest_V0.1 Login")
    root.geometry("300x150")

    #Username and password boxes
    usernametext = tkinter.Label(root, text="Username:")
    usernameguess = tkinter.Entry(root)
    passwordtext = tkinter.Label(root, text="Password:")
    passwordguess = tkinter.Entry(root, show="*")

    usernameguess1 = usernameguess
    def trylogin():
        print ("Logging In...")


        for x in range(0,len(userPaths)):
            #get path data here
            file1 = open(userPaths[x], "r")
            original = file1.read()
            file1.close()
            if original == usernameguess.get():
                userPaths[x] = activeUser
                x = activeUserNum


        file1 = open(passPaths[activeUserNum], "r")
        original = file1.read()
        original = hashbase.unhash(original)
        file1.close()

        if usernameguess.get() == activeUser and alphabet_position(passwordguess.get()) == original:
           print ("Success!")
           messagebox.showinfo("Success ", "Successfully logged in.")
           viewbutton = tkinter.Button(root, text="Veiw Saved Passwords", command=lambda:[root.withdraw()])
           viewbutton.pack()

        else:
            print ("Error: (Incorrect value entered)")
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Sorry, but your username or password is incorrect. Try again")
        #login button


    def viewtest():
        if loggedin == 1:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success ", "Loading Passwords")


        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "You need to sign in first!")



    #login button
    root.deiconify() #shows login window
    attemptlogin = tkinter.Button(root, text="Login", command=trylogin)
    attemptview = tkinter.Button(root, text="View Stored Passwords", command=viewtest)


    usernametext.pack()
    usernameguess.pack()
    passwordtext.pack()
    passwordguess.pack()
    attemptlogin.pack()
    attemptview.pack()
    window.mainloop()

def signuppage():
    root2 = tkinter.Toplevel()
    root2.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    root2.title("HasherTest_V0.1 Login")
    root2.geometry("300x150")
    #Gui Formatting (again)
    root2 = tkinter.Tk()
    root2.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    root2.title("HasherTest_V0.1")
    root2.geometry("300x150")
    #Username and password boxes
    masterusername = tkinter.Label(root2, text="Enter Master Username:")
    masterusernamebox = tkinter.Entry(root2)
    masterpassword = tkinter.Label(root2, text="Enter Master Password:")
    masterpasswordbox = tkinter.Entry(root2, show="*")


    def trysignup(): 

        newuser = str(masterusernamebox.get())

        length = len(userPaths)

        namepath = './usernames3.txt'
        userPaths[length-1] = namepath
        newfile = open(namepath, 'w')
        newfile.write(newuser)
        newfile.close()

        password = str(masterpasswordbox.get())
        numPass = alphabet_position(password)
        print(numPass)

        """hashbase = basehash.base52()
        #not taking numPass as an int
        #run test 328-i
        hashval = hashbase.hash(numPass)
        print(hashval)

        unhashed = hashbase.unhash(hashval)
        print(unhashed)"""

        path = './passwords3.txt'
        newfile = open(path, 'w')
        newfile.write(numPass)
        newfile.close()

        if newuser == "":
            messagebox.showinfo("Error code 0", "No input entered")
        else:
            return 


    #login button
    mastersignupbutton = tkinter.Button(root2, text="Sign Up 1", command=trysignup())
    mastersignupbutton.pack()



    masterusername.pack()
    masterusernamebox.pack()
    masterpassword.pack()
    masterpasswordbox.pack()
    window.mainloop()


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
window.title("HasherTest_V0.1")
window.geometry("300x150")

loginbutton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", command=lambda:[window.withdraw(), loginpage()])
signupbutton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Sign Up", command=lambda:[window.withdraw(), signuppage()])

loginbutton.pack()
signupbutton.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

If you run this code, and press the sign up button, then type in a master username and password, it should write them both to a notepad file, and if there is nothing in the box, give an error message. However, neither of these functions are working. When the user presses the first "sign up" button on the main window, it runs the wrong code (somehow) and gives an error code before it should. the error code should show if there is nothing there when "sign up 1" button is pressed on the "enter master username and password" window. I have no clue why the code runs early. Could somebody please reply with the reason why, or even some fixed code? thanks, Tf0R24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
mastersignupbutton = tkinter.Button(root2, text="Sign Up 1", command=trysignup)
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a button, a common error is including the parentheses after the function name. Instead of this:

```
mastersignupbutton = tkinter.Button(root2, text="Sign Up 1", command=trysignup())
```

Do this:

```
mastersignupbutton = tkinter.Button(root2, text="Sign Up 1", command=trysignup)
```

which is exactly the same but without the parentheses after `command=trysingup`. If you want to call a function that requires arguments, do this:

```
tkinter.Button(master, text="text", command=lambda: function_that_requires_arguments(x, y))
```